# How to delete item form recyclerview if the user has deleted it from the storage directory?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Below is my attempted code,

```
import android.os.FileObserver;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

public class ObserveFiles extends FileObserver {
public RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

public String absolutePath;

public ObserveFiles(String path) {
    super(path, FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS);

    absolutePath = path;
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int event, @Nullable String path) {

    if (path == null) {
        return;
    }
    //a new file or subdirectory was created under the monitored directory
    if ((FileObserver.DELETE & event)!=0) {
        Log.d("Deleted---------->", "File Deleted [" + absolutePath +  "/" + path + "]");
        String filepath = absolutePath + "/" + path;
        recyclerViewAdapter.removeOutOfApp(filepath);
    }

    //data was written to a file
    if ((FileObserver.MODIFY & event)!=0) {
        Log.d("Deleted---------->", "File Modified [" + absolutePath  +  "/" + path + "]");
    }

    //the monitored file or directory was deleted, monitoring effectively stops
    if ((FileObserver.DELETE_SELF & event)!=0) {
        Log.d("Deleted---------->", "File Self Deleted [" + absolutePath + "/URecorder" +  "/" + path + "]");
    }

    //a file or directory was opened
    if ((FileObserver.MOVED_TO & event)!=0) {
        Log.d("Deleted---------->", "File Moved To [" +  absolutePath  +  "/" + path  + "]");
    }

    //a file or subdirectory was moved from the monitored directory
    if ((FileObserver.MOVED_FROM & event)!=0) {
        Log.d("Deleted---------->", "File Moved From [" + absolutePath  +  "/" + path + "]");
    }

    //the monitored file or directory was moved; monitoring continues
    if ((FileObserver.MOVE_SELF & event)!=0) {
        Log.d("Deleted---------->", "File Moved Self[" + absolutePath  + "/" +  path + "]");
    }

}
}
```

................................................................................

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    String filePath = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/URecorder";
    observeFiles = new ObserveFiles(filePath);
    observeFiles.startWatching();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    observeFiles.stopWatching();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

welcome To SO! :)

Here is the pseudo-code :

1) REMOVE: There are 4 steps to remove an item from a RecyclerView

```
list.remove(position);
recycler.removeViewAt(position);
mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);                 
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());
```

These line of codes work for me.

2) UPDATE THE DATA: The only things I had to do is

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You had to do all of this in the Actvity/Fragment code not in the RecyclerView Adapter code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: no i am looking to update the recyclerview if the user deletes the file from storage directory

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your data/files amount or what kind of task you are doing.
But for another optional way is to load the data in `OnResume();`.
if user 
**minimize the app > delete the file..> again onResume will be called when app comes on foreground.**

So every time it will load the fresh data unless some other background thing will delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

String path = "file://"+newfile[i].getAbsolutePath();

File file = new File(path);

file.delete();

This is the process that directly delete file from storage

Comment: i want to delete from the recycler view and sqlite if the user delete the file from the external/internal storage directory.